# Facebook fql can't get comments by post_id from comment table

Tags: facebook, comments, facebook-fql

Can anyone tell me why I can't get comments from comment table by post_id.

Access token is [redacted]

post_id is 100002553491860_419288394832940

The post has one comment, I can get it from stream table by fql: select comments from stream where post_id = '100002553491860_419288394832940', you can run it in graph api explorer: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer.

Then I tried to get comments of this post from comment table, fql: select text,time,fromid,comment_count,likes,can_like,user_likes,id from comment where post_id='100002553491860_419288394832940', but it returns empty.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: after tested more posts, I found some of the posts I can get comments, but some of them I can't, it returned just an empty array, anyone had same issue before?

Comment: now I get error "comment_count is not a member of the comment table", but comment_count definitely is a member of comment table from the document here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment

Comment: strange I found I can get comments from the feed that posted from my app (an iOS app integrated with Facebook), but if the feed was posted from Facebook website, I can't get any comments, there's no error, just an empty comments array returned.

Comment: actually for the status posted from FB site, only the status with only text it returns empty comments, if the status has a photo attached, I can get comments, why? please anyone had this wired issue before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK for someone may run into the same problem, finally I used stream table to get comments instead of comment table, fql: select comments from stream where post_id='%@'.

Comment: Careful, folks - when you post a photo, facebook returns both an `id` and a `post_id`. I've found that while both work in a simple `fb.api('/'+id)` call, only the `post_id` will work when querying the stream table. If the user only posts text, you get back only an `id` which *will* work when querying the stream table.